# An anime about a boy related to gems/crystals

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'd watched the anime between 2008 and 2012, although I feel it was closer to 2010. The anime was originally Japanese but had English subtitles, I'm not sure it had even been dubbed. The anime had been available on Crunchyroll, although is no longer available.

There’s a boy who at night turns into a beast because of a gem/crystal inside him. I believe that the first episode shows him turning into a monster in black. Later on, a girl and her butler meet the main character trying to help him but he rejects their help. The girl explains to him about the power of the gym/crystal that he posses and he still angrily rejects them and forces them to leave.

He then starts to feel a pain from his forehand and grows a large crystal/gym like horn and once more turns into a monster that kills and hunts another monster like itself. He eventually gets help from the girl and using the power the girl gives him, he’s able to control his power and help mankind fight off these monsters. I think near the end of the anime he fights a Medusa like monster or something along those lines.

Comment: Do you remember when you may have watched it? What language it was originally in, whether it was dubbed?

Comment: It used to be on Crunchyroll but it has been longed removed, it was Japanese in end sub. Don’t know if it was subbed and I believe it caked around 2008-2012

Comment: It was an English dub of a Japanese anime? or and English subtitle and you don't know if it was dubbed. You watching it around 2008-2012?

Comment: Yes It was an English subtitle of a Japanese anime , and yes I have no idea if it’s been dubbed or not, and yes I watched around that date to be preciously I feel like around 2010

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135525/what-anime-features-a-boy-with-a-gem-or-crystal-that-gives-him-powers-to-transfo/137274 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the title is ["*Sacred Seven*"](https://myanimelist.net/anime/10156/Sacred_Seven). The boy(Alma Tandoji) have a crystal inside his body that can make him transform. One day, Ruri Alba, a girl accompanied by her butler and maids, visits him to help him control the stone with her power. At first the boy refused. Later on the boy accepts the girl's help and becomes a hero who fights a stone monster.

> Alma Tandoji lives a lonely life. One day, Ruri Alba, a girl accompanied by her butler and maids, visits him. Knowing the power of Sacred Seven is latent within Alma, she asks him to lend her his powers. However, he refuses and drives her away since he injured many with his unusual strength in the past.
>
> Meanwhile, a fiendish Dark Stone creature suddenly appears in this peaceful town in the Kanto region. Only Alma's power of Sacred Seven can fight against it. But Alma just lets his power run amuck and things begin to get worse. Ruri raised her gemstone in order to release his true abilities, My Soul I give to you.
>
> With Ruri's wishes engraved in it, will Alma be able to defeat the Dark Stone?

[image: Sacred Seven character poster]

Comment: I've edited in some basic information (from the link) in case it goes down. Could you also [edit] to explain how this matches the OPs description a bit more?