# Anime similar to Guyver

Tags: story-identification, anime

I've been searching for this anime that for the life of me I cannot remember the name. To be honest I dont remember if it was a short series or movie either. I saw it back in the early to mid 90s. It was kinda gory.

It was about a highschool aged boy who somehow gets this power. It was almost like guyver the bioboosted armor. But he had a green control gem in his forehead when he used the armor. He also had the ability to transform into like a giant.

I remember in the last scene, or episode, the kid has this major battle with some white giant monster and she ends up stabbing him with these two tentacle like things. So he picks her up by them and blasts her to pieces with that green gem before falling into the lake and disappears.

That's all I can remember about it. Not sure if that's the ending of a movie or series. Not even sure if it continues after that. Tried finding it on my own but to no avail.

Comment: I keep seeing references to D-Boy of *Tekkaman Blade* having a green crystal in his forehead, but every image I encounter shows a red one. His armor is alien biological, although it looks more like a conventional mecha.

Comment: Could it be a duplicate of this question https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135525/what-anime-features-a-boy-with-a-gem-or-crystal-that-gives-him-powers-to-transfo?

Comment: Yea I checked that one out but unfortunately it wasnt it