# Anime with Nanotech armor. The nanites are in the blood stream and form armor when attacked

Tags: story-identification, anime

I rented a movie back in 2005 on the Anime Network. One scene explains how the armor works. The nanobots are in the bloodstream and when attacked the bots rush up from the blood stream up to the skin to form some kind of armor/barrier. They are fighting blob monsters that are killing people. It was very gory. The group are military. In the opening scene, if I remember correctly, one character jumps out of a plane into a warehouse where one of the monsters is.

Comment: Can you remember any of the plot of this? What did the blob monsters look like? Why are they killing people? What does the main character/characters look like? Why do they have the armour? In the army or something? If you can remember anything else please [edit] your question to include those additional details.

Comment: Possibly related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/227934/anime-similar-to-guyver

Comment: No. But I think we're getting closer. Its sci-fi but not fantasy.

Comment: Could it be Zaion: I Wish You Were Here ? I didn't see it but I remember seeing the trailor and it had nanomachin armour as you described.

Comment: OMG BRO YOU ARE THE BEST! YES THATS IT!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The anime is [*Zaion: I Wish You Were Here*](https://myanimelist.net/anime/1156/I__Wish_You_Were_Here). Synopsis:

> In the future, a meteor crashes into Earth and brings with it a virulent form of life. This virus is known as M34 and attacks humans, turning them into vicious monsters. Most of the human population is wiped out, thus government agencies are formed to fight the virus. One of the groups, NOA, inserts nanomachines into the bodies of its soldiers; these machines allow them to transform and fight off the infected. Unfortunately, the virus mutates and becomes too strong for NOA to handle. Now the fate of the world rests in the hands of 16-year-old girl with the power to defeat the virus.

[image: The armored military]

[image: The sort of blob monsters]

The episodes apparently are up on YouTube, [here’s the first](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09cTBioLJ5I). In the opening, you can see the nanites in the characters bloodstream creating the armor.

Answer (score 3):

My first thought is Guyver: The Bioboosted Armor. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guyver:_The_Bioboosted_Armor), the original run was 2005-6 and it did air on Anime Network. The monsters are called Zoanoids, although I don't remember any of them being blobby.

Comment: Unfortunately no. Loved the Guyver though. The armor of the anime im trying to describe is man made. When activated the Nanites clump together forming a barrier or armor like over the host.